# Newbie Class Inheritance Question (python)

Tags: python

```
class Deck(Cards):
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.mycardset = []
        for num in self.values:
            for shp in self.suites:
                self.mycardset.append(num+' of '+ shp)
         
        
            
  
    def shuffleDeck(self):
      
        self.mycardset = shuffle(self.mycardset)  


def main():
    deck = Deck()
  
    print(f'[Current Deck]\n{deck.mycardset}')
    shuffled_deck = deck.shuffleDeck()
    print(f'[Shuffled Deck]\n{shuffled_deck.mycardset}')
```

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mycardset'
```

I don't think it's saved on the list, how can I fix it?

Comment: shuffleDeck does not return anything.

Comment: `shuffleDeck()` modifies the `mycardset` _in-place_. So you don't need to save the function's return value to anything. Just access `deck.mycardset`.

Answer (score 0):

`suffleDeck` method doesn't return anything (or returns a `None`), modifying your class in place, so you are assigning `shuffled_deck` as `None`, hence your error. Just call your method on the `deck` variable and access the `mycardset` attribute from it instead

```
def main():
    deck = Deck()
  
    print(f'[Current Deck]\n{deck.mycardset}')
    # Suffle deck in place
    deck.shuffleDeck()
    print(f'[Shuffled Deck]\n{deck.mycardset}')
```

Other option would be to modify `shuffleDeck()` to return `self`

```
def shuffleDeck(self):
    self.mycardset = shuffle(self.mycardset)
    return self
```

but keep in mind, this still modifies `deck` as well, since now both variables point to the same object in memory. If you want to create a new deck and shuffle, while maintaining the original object, simplest way would be to [copy the original deck](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) before shuffling

```
import copy

def shuffleDeck(self):
    new = copy.deepcopy(self)
    new.mycardset = shuffle(self.mycardset)
    return new
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way not to modify the main() function?

Comment: @korinEE Check the edited post, I added some possible modification for `shuffleDeck()`